# How to change table style by using internal style?

Tags: html, css

how can I do exactly this table in html by using internal style?. I tried a lot but I can't handle it. Can you help me please?

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9s9e.jpg)

```
    <html>
`<head>`
<title>
TABLES
</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color: white; font-family:verdana; color:blue; font-weight:bold;">
<h1>Using tables</h1>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Top left</td>
<td style="border: 2px inset yellow;">Top right</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="background-color:red;">Bottom left</td>
<td style="border: 3px dotted green;">Bottom right</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>

    enter code here
```

Comment: What do you mean by internal style? Please share the code so we can help

Comment: Okay I add the code. This should look like the table in the photo.

Comment: what is internal style? Do you mean inline style where you have to add css inside the elements?

Comment: I mean <style> tag should be in <head> section.

Answer (score 3):

Here you are:

**internal styles (CSS):**

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
table{
width:100%;
border: 2px solid black;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
th{
background:#000;color:#fff;font-size:18px;text-align:left;height:50px;font-weight:normal;
}
tr,td{
border: 2px solid black;color:red;font-weight:bold;font-size:18px;padding:10px
}
</style>


</head>
<body>

<table>

  <tr>
    <th>Header of Column 1</th>
    <th>Header of Column 2</th>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>Top left</td>
    <td>Top right</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>Bottom left</td>
    <td>Bottom right</td>
  </tr>
  
</table>
</body>

</html>
```

**inline styles (CSS):**

```html
<table style="width:100%;border: 2px solid black;border-collapse: collapse;">

  <tr style="background:#000;color:#fff;font-size:18px;text-align:left;height:50px;">
    <th style="border: 2px solid black;font-weight:normal;padding:10px">Header of Column 1</th>
    <th style="border: 2px solid black;font-weight:normal;padding:10px">Header of Column 2</th>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td style="border: 2px solid black;color:red;font-weight:bold;font-size:18px;padding:10px">Top left</td>
    <td style="border: 2px solid black;color:red;font-weight:bold;font-size:18px;padding:10px">Top right</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td style="border: 2px solid black;color:red;font-weight:bold;font-size:18px;padding:10px">Bottom left</td>
    <td style="border: 2px solid black;color:red;font-weight:bold;font-size:18px;padding:10px">Bottom right</td>
  </tr>
  
</table>
```

Comment: is it called internal style? because i need to change this code to do like that. <style> tag should be in <head> section.

Comment: I edited. check again